# How to set a coming soon page on drupal?

Tags: 7, theming

All request must be redirected to the coming soon page, is there any module can do it or a solution, I'm using the zen base theme.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: just create your own custom page www.example.com/comingsoon

Comment: Why would you even use Drupal for that? Just create an index.html with your coming soon message, and develop your soon-to-come website somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

You can put the site on maintaince mode and can use the message as coming soon.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution!  Just don't forget to change it back to a maintenance page once you've finished your build :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way, mentioned by [VM](https://www.drupal.org/u/vm) in this [support request](https://www.drupal.org/node/570096) 5 years ago is:

> [...] creating a page-front.tpl.php file for you theme which only gets called on the front page.

And use that tpl for the coming soon period.

I personally used the maintenance mode (see answer by arpitr in this page). But I don't know how to display a block in the maintenance mode. For instance a block with a mailing list subscription form (which is a must in a coming soon page). The front.tpl.php way instead is more customizable, I think. I'll check it out. (*see updates in edit3*)

Edit: I'll check out also [mcd](https://www.drupal.org/project/mcd) module which integrates with [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) subscription block (this way it's possible to use the maintenance option).

Edit2: Also, with 3rd party service mailchimp one can [embed her subscriptio form](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/add-a-signup-form-to-your-website#Embed-Form-options) in the plain html of the maintenance page (*see updates in edit3*). Another way to go and use the maintenance page option.

Edit3: I've tried to insert an iframe (embedding mailchimp subscription form or google subscription form) in the maintenance page message, with no success. So, if one needs to deal with iframe embedding, one has to use the tpl.php option. The good news (for me) is that there is a more specific *maintenance-page.tpl.php* to configure for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Maintenance Countdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/mcd) module? It puts your site in a maintenance mode and provides a nice counter for the time the site will be available again.

[image: site countdown module image]

Answer (score 0):

Check [ComingSoon: A Distro for Collecting Pre-Launch Sign Ups](https://www.drupal.org/project/comingsoon). I think this could help you.

> "*Coming Soon*" is a distribution for creating a launch site for an upcoming project, idea or business. In it's most basic sense, it's a Drupal clone of LaunchRock.com. It provides a simple signup / registration form on the homepage and unique share pages for new users. So that before the site, app or business itself actual launches, you can start to get new members.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a panel with one column and put a block in it with all data you need
so you wil have a new page with a unique url then choose this page from configuration - site information in Default 404 (not found) page or put its link to all your incoming page

Comment: Thank u :), but like I say for all incoming requests not just 404 requests

Comment: ok you can set all your menu item to this page